# Looking for rules for board game called "Music Game"

Tags: music-game-level-1

I bought a game at a thrift store called simply "[Music Game](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/137696/music-game-level-1/)" and unfortunately it needs the rules.

The game says copyright Petina, 1989. It's a board game with piano keys around the edges and several piles of question cards of different colors in the middle to draw.

Without the rules I don't know when to draw cards and which pile to draw from. It seems to be a great way to teach music concepts, if only I had the rules.

Comment: Yes! That is the game! Googling brought up no results for me, so thanks very much!

Comment: Asked on boardgamegeek for the rules, I see another person has it, so maybe something will turn up. Thanks much!

Answer (score 1):

There is a boardgame geek entry, as diego already mentioned. But that lacks any link to the rules. But luckily [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01MPY7DVS) has a page for it. On the page there are several pictures, including (part of) the rules. 
And according to them, it is a rare vintage game. So I hope you are able to play it now.

Comment: Yes, that is the game! Unfortunately the pictures are not of the rules, but rather only the description of the game on the bottom of the box. I'll maybe ask on the Amazon page for the rules and see if there is any response. Thanks much!

Comment: @reidun You could also try asking on BoardGameGeek